# Ajax Request success vars scope

Tags: ajax, extjs

I have a function in the success of a Ext.Ajax.request. I need that this function returns a variable with a JSON Store.
My code is:

```
gridplatos.getStore().each(function(r){
  var store;
  Ext.Ajax.request({
    params:{
      grado: r.get('grado'),
      menudiario: r.get('menudiario'),
      plato: r.get('plato'),
      transCode: Ext.getCmp('transCode').getValue()
    },
    url: 'src/Drivers/AlumnosPlatoArmado/',
    method: 'GET',
    success: function(response,store){
      store = Ext.create('KMA.store.AlumnosPlatoArmado',{}).load();
    }
  });
  console.log(store);
}
```

But, console.log(store) return "undefined". Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because ajax is a asynchronous function call, means once the request is sent to the server the client will continue execution of following statements without waiting for the server response.

In your case the ajax request is sent to `src/Drivers/AlumnosPlatoArmado/` then before the server response back `console.log(store);` is executed at that point of time `store` has the value `undefined`. Once the ajax request is completed successfully, the registered success handler will get called, where you are setting the value of `store`.

In a async execution environment all actions on values returned by the async method must be performed with in the registered callback methods only.

Comment: what do you want to do with the store, if you can give the complete context of the problem we can try

Comment: I have a store (A) that refresh other store (B). But now i need create a txt file with both stores. Example: "line from A - lines from B - line from A - lines form B..."